# Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini blackscreen startup

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I just got my *S3 Mini* from my service provider yesterday. When I got it, everything was fine and working well. When I woke up today I checked on it and the screen still stayed black. I tried charging it but I got no beep or vibrate as a response that it acknowledged the charger and the screen stayed black. I also tried restarting it like it said on the manual in case it freezes up (hold the power button for 8-10 secs) but the menu and back button just lit up and nothing happened. No welcome animation or anything. I'm planning to have a nearby service center to take a look at it but is there anything I can try first?